# Why does the potentiometer output maximum voltage when the wiper is turned towards the first terminal?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

This might sound super dumb, but I can't seem to find the answer to this question. How come the wiper in a rotary potentiometer outputs maximum voltage when it is turned all the way to the first terminal. As I understand, as the wiper turns to the first terminal, there is less resistance between the wiper and the first terminal. But based on Ohm's Law (V = I*R), if the resistance is zero, then the voltage should also be zero, right? If no resistance (0 ohms) exists between the wiper and the first terminal, shouldn't the wiper output 0 volts? By the way, in this circuit the end terminal of the potentiometer is connected to ground.

Answer (score 1):

When the wiper is turned as you describe, the wiper is essentially touching the top lug on the potentiometer so the resistance between them is zero. This means that the voltage *drop* between the top lug and the wiper is also zero, which means the wiper lug is at the *same voltage as the top lug*.

Then, turning the pot *down* from there inserts resistance between the top lug and the wiper and removes it from between the wiper and the bottom lug (which, as you say, is at ground). When the pot is turned all the way down, the wiper is touching the bottom lug (which is at zero volts) which means the wiper lug is at zero volts as well.

Comment: this made so much more sense to me. Thank you!